# Move to other Picker View tabs only after the user taps on a button in an alert view - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uisegmentedcontrol, picker

What I would like to be able to do is that when the user taps on a color tab, first present an alert view asking before actually moving to the other tab and if the user decides to `Cancel` it will not move to the other tab but if the user taps the `OK` button, the Picker will actually move to the selected tab.

How can I move to a different color tab only after the user taps on the `YES` button in the alert view?

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var favoriteColor = 0
        @State private var showAlert = false

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Picker("What is your favorite color?", selection: $favoriteColor) {
                    Text("Red").tag(0)
                    Text("Green").tag(1)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)

                .onChange(of: favoriteColor) { tag in
                    showAlert = true
                }

                .alert("By changing color also modifieds other things...change color?", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    Button("YES") { 
                        // move to selected color tab
                    }
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI is reactive world, means our code receives control post-factum... use UIKit representable instead for that...

... Or, here is a possible workaround with proxy binding (however not sure if behavior persists in all OS versions)

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
var selected: Binding<Int> {     // << proxy !!
    Binding<Int>(
        get: { favoriteColor },
        set: {
            toConfirm = $0      // store for verification !!
            showAlert = true    // show alert !!
        }
    )
}
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // << bind to proxy binding here !!
        Picker("What is your favorite color?", selection: selected) { 
            Text("Red").tag(0)
            Text("Green").tag(1)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .alert("By changing color also modifieds other things...change color?", isPresented: $showAlert, presenting: toConfirm) { color in   // << inject for verification !!
            Button("YES") {
                favoriteColor = color   // << do verification here !!
            }
            Button("Cancel") {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

[Test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestInjectingAlertInPickerChanges.swift)

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach. The world of `Binding` is still pretty blurry to me.  Thanks a lot!